# Create a network for two machines in docker that is not reachable from the host system

Tags: linux, networking, docker, containers, docker-network

Is there a way to create a network with two docker containers in it which is not accessible from the host system?

I search some way to do what is called internal networking in virtualbox.

If it is possible, how? And if it is not, why?

Thanks :D

Answer (score 1):

you can adjust iptables rules in each container